# Laravel select records older than 5 minutes?

Tags: php, sql, laravel-4

I have Laravel app where i check user loggedin regularly with a heartbeat for every 3 seconds (demo purpose, actually 5 minutes). For each beat I check if user's last activity with current time is also 5 minutes. If it is, log them out.

Here's my code:

```
$result = DB::table('db_user')->where('id_user','=',Session::get('id_user'))->where('last_activity','>=',"now() - interval 5 minute")->get();

    if(!empty($result)) 
        return Redirect::to('/logout');
    else
        return Response::json('still-alive');
```

My problem is, this doesn't work. If I change the operand to `<=`, it will log me out immediately before 5 minutes, if the operand is `>=`, even after 5 minutes it won't log me out, can anyone explain why?

-EDIT-

Thanks for all the answers, I solved my problems by modifying my code to:

```
$result = DB::table('db_user')->where('id_user','=',Session::get('id_user'))->first();

    if(!empty($result)) 
        if(strtotime($result->last_activity) < strtotime("-5 minutes"))
            return Redirect::to('/logout');
        else 
            return Response::json('still-alive');
    else
        return Response::json('no-record');
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Assuming your business logic is correct, try using PHP instead of an SQL string in the `where` clause:

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('-5 minutes');
$formatted_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$result = DB::table('db_user')->where('id_user','=',Session::get('id_user'))->where('last_activity','>=',$formatted_date)->get();
```

Also, it is a good practice to always output the executed SQL queries just to make sure Laravel behaves as expected:

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
```

Comment: thanks, i tried yours too, and it works. Accepted and upvoted due to your time for answering, anyway I already solved the problem with my own code (see edit), thanks a lot for your time :D

Comment: you could also use Carbon (included in Laravel by default) to created the formatted date: `$formatted_date = Carbon::now()->subMinutes(5)->toDateTimeString();`

Comment: @murze I know this is not a question that has an exact answer but what is the difference between using Datetime or Carbon?

Comment: @Charlie: the difference is that the question is related to Laravel and Carbon is a part of Laravel's API

Answer (score 52):

The accepted answer is correct, but you could make it even cleaner by using a query scope on the User model (assuming that you have a User model)...

```
$result = User::currentUser()->activityOlderThan(self::HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL)->get();
```

Your User model would then have these functions:

```
public function scopeCurrentUser($query)
{
    return $query->where('id_user', '=', Session::get('id_user'));
}
```

And

```
public function scopeActivityOlderThan($query, $interval)
{
    return $query->where('last_activity', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMinutes($interval)->toDateTimeString());
}
```

Now your code is clean and easy to read :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `whereRaw()`:

```
$result = DB::table('db_user')->where('id_user','=',Session::get('id_user'))->whereRaw('last_activity >= now() - interval 5 minute')->get();
```

or

```
$result = DB::table('db_user')->where('id_user','=',Session::get('id_user'))->whereRaw('last_activity >= now() - interval ? minute', [5])->get();
```