# Delete Elequent records older than 60 minutes

Tags: database, laravel-4, eloquent

How can I delete all Eloquent Records in a database where the created_at or updated_at field is older than 60 minutes? (or any amount of time for the example)

*edit: posted solution as answer as @Alexxus suggested*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel select records older than 5 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19475896/laravel-select-records-older-than-5-minutes)

Comment: I would start by learning the MySQL date/time functions http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff.

Comment: Please post the aswer as answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solved** -> With ceejayoz his link

- Make a date object and minus the amount of time.
- Covert the date object to string to match Eloquent formatting
- Compare formatted string against updated_at

I'm using the following code:

```
$date = new DateTime;
$date->modify('-60 minutes');
$formatted = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
MyModel::where('updated_at', '<=', $formatted)->delete();
```

Thanks ceejayoz!

Answer (score 7):

Laravel have a build in Carbon date class which handles all the timezone problems for you.

Example:

```
$date  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 60 );
MyModel::where( 'updated_at', '<=', $date )->delete();
```